# How do I set a timer and repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want 10 circles to appear in a random place on the screen, each within 0.1 second of each other, growing from the centre and fading to nothing.  Then have the whole process repeat itself indefinitely.

Adding a timer between each circle only allows 1 circle.
Repeating the process loses the animation effect.

What am I doing wrong please?

HTML

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="circle"></span>
        <span class="circle"></span>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
    animation: scale 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes scale {
    to {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(3);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

JS

```
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle')

const width = window.innerWidth
const height = window.innerHeight

function go() {

    let N = 0

    circles.forEach(circle => {

        X = Math.floor(Math.random() * width)
        Y = Math.floor(Math.random() * height)
        Size = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 5) * 10
        R = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255).toString(16)
        G = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255).toString(16)
        B = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255).toString(16)
        RGB = R + G + B

        // setTimeout(circ, N * 100) // <==== OFFENDING ELEMENT
        circ() // used for now instead of the line above

        N++

        function circ() {
            circle.style.left = X + 'px'
            circle.style.top = Y + 'px'
            circle.style.width = Size + 'px'
            circle.style.height = Size + 'px'
            circle.style.backgroundColor = '#' + RGB
        }

    })

    // setTimeout(go, 1000); // <==== OFFENDING ELEMENT
}

go()
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/iBlackwolf/pen/BavjWzP)

ALL FIXED NOW, thanks to JaromandaX ... help yourselves to my code

Comment: your main problem is the *global* variables in the forEach callback, X, Y, Size etc ... try declaring them as `var`, `let` or `const` as appropriate, like you did with `N` - though, you could `circles.forEach((circle, N) => {` instead of having that `let N = 0` and `N++` - but that's not your issue, your issue is global `X`, `Y`, `Size`, `R`, `G`, `B` and `RGB`

Comment: of course, then you'll need to fix the animation, since it'll only run once

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that fixed the interval, just need to make it repeat now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it ... using the `animationend` event, and also using another class for the animation, so that the animation can repeat

```js
function go() {
    const circ = circle => {
        const X = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
        const Y = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
        const Size = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 5) * 10;
        const R = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255).toString(16);
        const G = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255).toString(16);
        const B = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255).toString(16);
        const RGB = R + G + B;

        circle.classList.remove('anim');
        circle.style.left = X + 'px';
        circle.style.top = Y + 'px';
        circle.style.width = Size + 'px';
        circle.style.height = Size + 'px';
        circle.style.backgroundColor = '#' + RGB;
        // important to do this "asynchronously"
        // otherwise no animation will happen
        // after the first time, due to how CSS animation works
        setTimeout(() => circle.classList.add('anim'));
    };
    const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;
    circles.forEach((circle, N) => {
        circle.addEventListener('animationend', () => circ(circle));
        setTimeout(circ, N * 100, circle);
    });
}

go();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
}
.anim {
    animation: scale 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes scale {
    to {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(3);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. Btw, add overflow: hidden to the body :)

Comment: yeah @Blackwolf I noticed that, but didn't really look at your edits :p (updated the answer)

Comment: actually, you hit the nail on the head mentioning the CSS.  all it needed was animation-iteration-count: infinite;

Comment: @Blackwolf - sure, but then you don't have an exact moment to change the circle, since `animationend` event won't fire

Comment: it works, check my codepen

Comment: yeah, it works, but it seems to be less smooth, the circles seems to grow in groups - though, with my code you also get that if you remove focus from the page then go back I guess

Comment: Yes, I've only been learning JS for a few weeks, so still lots to learn, but I can see it clearly needs an event listener on each circle.  At the moment it seems to be working in batches of 10, where really I want each circle to cycle independently.  I won't copy your code, as I need to figure it out myself, but know I have learnt from it. Thank you

Comment: yeah, there's something odd happening with `animationend` handlers, it's like they synchronise!